# Run Gitlab Jobs on Bitbucket pull requests updates

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, bitbucket, gitlab-ci

I'm using Gitlab CI/CD with Bitbucket repository mirroring. I need to run some CI/CD gitlab jobs when Bitbucket pull requests are created/updated, but i found, that gitlab doesn't mirror Bitbucket PRs by default.

Is there a possibility to mirror all pull requests from Bitbucket to Gitlab? Or is there other way to run gitlab jobs on Bitbucket PR updates.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. As far as I see, Bitbucket does support PR webhooks, so that we can have a service listening to those and creating the PR. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pull-request-post-service-management-385913080.html